# BigQuery not accurately returning results

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm using GoogleApp Engine and occasionally when I send a query to BigQuery via the JSON API, I will get incorrect results. It is usually only confined to a single table within BigQuery (I make a new table for every batch job that is created). When I run into this issue in production, I log the Query i submitted and try running it via the BigQuery dashboard which runs longer than expected but returns the expected results.

There is nothing in the response indicating an issue. the `jobComplete` comes back as `True` but I see no `rows`, just the `jobReference`,  `schema`, and `totalRows = 0`.

In such situations is is appropriate to do a call to get the job results even though I should expect the current call to return the results?

Relevant Code:

```
http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
self.credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
self.http = self.credentials.authorize(http=http)
self.service = build('bigquery','v2',http=self.http)
jobs = self.service.jobs()
result = jobs.query(projectId=settings.GOOGLE_APIS_PROJECT_ID,
                                body={'query': query}).execute()
```

Response:

```
{u'totalRows': u'0', u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'jobComplete': True, u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'<REMOVED>', u'jobId': u'<REMOVED>'}, u'schema': {u'fields': [<REMOVED>]}}
```

No matter how many times I try to re-run the query in production, the same results are returned (Could this be due to the caching done via memcache with incorrect results being cached as a response?)

Comment: Can you send the jobid of a job that you believe has an incorrect response?

Comment: job_3729b36aa04148bbbb9625a1b4ce6190

Comment: If you'd rather not discuss query details on a public forum, can you e-mail me at my surname at google.com? (my initial investigation makes it look like the query is returning the right data, but I'd like to understand better what you think the correct results would be and whether other queries against this table seem to be working as expected)

Comment: I've e-mailed you with additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a mix of the following:

1. The shared http object is NOT threadsafe! (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety). Although most exmaples of usign BigQuery on GAE use a shared httplib2 object, this is incorrect usage. Only the credentials store is threadsafe and can be shared
2. There is 10s timeout on queries on BigQuery.

I was doing multiple calls to BigQuery in parallel using a shared http object & taskqueues and the queries were taking over 10s to complete. This is why responses would get mixed between calls and the results would not be as expected. E.g. - I sometimes received the discovery response to my query request

**The Fix:**

Re-write my BigQuery client code to not share the httplib2 object between calls and de-couple my process to submit BigQuery jobs to run queries vs using the query() call. There is a lot more overhead in managing the calls and checking on statuses and receiving results, but at least it works now and the responses make sense.